# How to delete groups based on conditions/values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe I want to delete those groups of column B, in which all values in column C are smaller than 3.

So there should only be those groups left, which only have values in column C that are bigger than 3.

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 22 | 4 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 33 | 2 |
| 33 | 1 |
| 22 | 4 |

So in my example only group 22 should stay.

Probably something like this pseudo code:

```
df_clean = df.groupby('B')['C']< 3.0
```

How do I code an algorithm that can do this?

Comment: why not just `df['C'] < 3.0` ? Why to group at all?

Comment: Do you want to sum C or take the average in the groupby? Otherwise @VladimirFokow's comment

Comment: Perhaps you can add more sample data? I suppose you do not have just one duplicate in your dataframe. And if so, are you going to take all the values more than 3 in the same ID?

Comment: I specified my question. It's about detecting those groups in which all values are smaller than 3. Sorry for being imprecise.

Comment: So after deleting groups with all values smaller than 3, you will have group 22 with all the values in column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe by creating `df_count` counting the number of elements with `C`-value greater 2:

```
df_count = df.groupby(['B'])['C'].apply(lambda x: (x>2).sum()).reset_index(name='count')

    B   count
0   11  0
1   22  2
2   33  0
```

and then sorting out those with 0:

```
df = df[df['B'].isin(df_count[df_count['count'] > 0]['B'].unique())].sort_index()

    B   C
1   22  2
3   22  4
4   22  1
7   22  4
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, each group must have all its value less than 3 to be considered,
I'd start by getting the groups that satisfy this condition by comparing the maximum value with the target:3

```py
>>> groups = [group for group in df['C'].unique() if max(df[df.C==group].B.values) < 3]
>>> groups
[11, 33]
```

then, you can slice your dataframe and get a new one with only the desired groups

```py
>>> df[df.C.isin(groups)]
    C  B
0  11  1
2  11  2
5  33  2
6  33  1
```

Comment: But I want to delete groups in which all values are smaller than 3. It's about the groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `any` with a for loop to get your desired output.

```
for i ,j  in df.groupby('B'):
    if (j['C'] >= 3).any() == True:
        result = j

    B  C
1  22  2
3  22  4
4  22  1
7  22  4
```

or other way round if you are looking for groups with all values less than 3.

```
result = []
for i ,j  in df.groupby('B'):
    if (j['C'] < 3).all() == True:
        result.append(j)
        
[    B  C
 0  11  1
 2  11  2,
     B  C
 5  33  2
 6  33  1]
```

Comment: Of course, you can always create a list to append those groups with values greater than or equals to 3.